# python - Append values in order by key column value

Tags: python, pandas, string, text, append

I have 2 Dataframes:

**df1**

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| key_1 | 1100 |
| key_2 | 1100 |
| key_3 | 1100 |

**df2**

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key_1 | 1110 | xxr | wer |
| key_2 | 1110 | xxv | cad |
| key_3 | 1110 | xxw | sder |
| key_1 | 1110 | xxt | dse |
| key_2 | 1110 | xxe | sdf |
| key_3 | 1110 | xxz | csd |

**My goal is to append each value of df2 into the df1 based on equal value of Column1 from the 2 dataframes**

My expected result would be this ( I need a CSV separated by '|'):

```
 |key_1|1100|
 |key_1|1110|xxr|wer
 |key_1|1110|xxt|dse
 |key_2|1100|
 |key_2|1110|xxv|cad
 |key_2|1110|xxe|sdf
 |key_3|1100|
 |key_3|1110|xxw|sder
 |key_3|1110|xxz|csd
```

**I'm trying this, without success**

```py
for l_df1 in df1['Column1']:
    p = df1['Column1']
    s = df1['Column2']
    t_l_df1 = p + '|'  + s
    for l_df2 in df2['Column1']:
            o = df2['Column1']
            t = df2['Column2'] 
            u = df2['Column3']
            v = df2['Column4'] 
            if l_df2 == l_df1: 
                t_l_df1 = t_l_df1.append(o + '|' + t + '|'+ u + '|'+ v)
            pass
```

Comment: `df1.append(df2).sort_values('Column1').to_csv(...)`?

Comment: problem of this is that it returns lots of nulls where the columns are not found in each dataframe. I need that exact format described

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It seems this is a couple issues in one - you'd like to append the dataframes in a specific format and then you'd like to write a pipe-delimited file (see the "sep" argument to [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). I'd suggest breaking down your question for best results.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values("Column1") \
  .to_csv("output.csv", header=False, index=False, sep="|")
```

Output:

```
key_1|1100||
key_1|1110|xxr|wer
key_1|1110|xxt|dse
key_2|1100||
key_2|1110|xxv|cad
key_2|1110|xxe|sdf
key_3|1100||
key_3|1110|xxw|sder
key_3|1110|xxz|csd
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you can directly use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to get the desired output, since its just the two DataFrames concatenated together, likewise:

```
final_df = pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True, sort = False)
```

However, since you also asked how could you map the keys of df2 to df1 and append the corresponding columns, you can do that using [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) and can use concat as mentioned above.

```
mapped_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Column1', how = 'left')
```

You can then export it to csv as follows:

```
final_df.to_csv("output.csv", header=False, index=False, sep="|")
```